IV estimation in R: reduced form, standard error and 1st stage
I am analysing a panel dataset of individuals. I have a set of dependent variables, Y, 1 endogenous variable, X and 1 instrument, Z. I also have a set of fixed effects, such as birth year, and birth state.
I noticed that the estimated asymptotic variance given in the usual output of 2SLS regression is incorrect as $\hat{X}$ is used instead of $X$.
What is the easiest way to do the IV estimation in R, where I can

get the correct standard error as in a reduced form estimation, and
get the result of 1st stage for F statistics etc.
with fixed effects and clusters.

Thank you a lot in advance.

Hey, use ivreg in the AER  package. See here for an example https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/12-ivr.html
